# Countdown timer for Windows with custom presets

Tags: windows, cooking

I am looking for a free countdown timer for Windows where I can save custom presets (unlike in [CookTimer](https://code.google.com/p/cooktimer/downloads/detail?name=CookTimer-0.9.3.exe) and like in the Android app [Stopwatch & Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sportstracklive.stopwatch)). I don't care whether it's open source. I would prefer to have a visual popup and sound alarm (ideally I could choose).

Basically the following for Windows would be perfect:

[image]

Comment: Are Windows Store apps acceptable for you, too?